# Eclipse Plug-in installation and the connection to the momentary constellation of planets in our sun system

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Earth, sun and neptune have to be [almost aligned in one line](http://www.theplanetstoday.com/) and the room's temperature you are running Eclipse in has to be between 20 and 25°C. Then - and only then - Eclipse might take a look into the `dropins` folder and will install randomly new plug-ins after an arbitrary amount of seemingly senseless restart attempts.

Can anyone approve that?

Thank you.

**Edit:** This post is a result of a mind-based stackoverflow.

Comment: ..what? Where's the question?

Comment: @ChrisMantle: question added

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a rant about problems with Eclipse.

Comment: @madth3 This question is scientific since a) I want to know if others can observe the same behaviour and b) I want to know other astronomic constellations and/or events that might cause Eclipse to run as expected. I was hoping that others share their experiance with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the -clean option when starting Eclipse to get Eclipse to dump its cache of what it knows to be installed.  Eclipse then looks at the usual plugin locations for new plugins to be installed.  Eclipse normally doesn't look for new plugins because that's a costly, rarely-needed operation for an already long startup time.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect to get an actual answer on this, but you are right. After many attempts I came to that solution too. My problem was that I had two plug-ins to load and did not notice that I somehow to do that twice(!). The really annoying thing is that this is not mentioned on the official documentation page in `Platform Plug-in Developer Guide > Reference > Other reference information > The dropins folder and supported file layouts`. I almost started to bang my head against my keyboard as stuff that already worked stopped to work .. long story.

Comment: Do I have to make a `-clean` start everytime I make changes to the plug-in? I'm asking since such a start almost takes forever to perform ..

Comment: No, clean just clears the cache once, but that's all you need to pick up new plugin versions.  Eclipse sometimes can do that by itself, but when you need to give it a nudge, use -clean